# Bluetooth legacy products name

Tags: bluetooth, wireless

I have come across a Bluetooth legacy product or protocol in a meeting at my employer, but I can't quite recall if its name is called BluetoothLC (Bluetooth Local Connectivity). It would be great to know what kind of legacy Bluetooth classes/protocols are out there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_protocols) on Bluetooth protocols may have what you are after...